How to check for a license file in a git-tracked project on GitHub using LSP?
I'm fairly new to Language Server Protocol (LSP) and need some guidance on solving the following use case. I want to implement this on the server side to maximize compatibility with different IDEs.
Use Case:
I need to check if my project contains a license file, but only if:

The project is tracked by Git. (search for a .git folder in the root)
The remote origin URL contains "github.com". (analyze .git/config)

What I've Researched:

workspace/diagnostic Method:

This seemed promising initially.
When I subscribed to this method, it fired randomly (at least for me and I had not control on how I often I would scan).
It included a partialResultToken with different GUIDs per request, which I don't know how to handle and couldn't find much information on.


workspace/didChangeWorkspaceFolders Notification:

This notification is sent by the client.
However, notifications aren't meant to have responses. How would one send back diagnostics.



The workspace events I mentioned above don't include any workspace information. Do I really have to maintain the state from the initialize event?
I also considered scanning for the file during the initialize event but stepped away from that idea.
Question:
Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to send diagnostics to the client to indicate that the file is missing? How can I handle this use case effectively using LSP?
